# iPhone SDK Camera Bug: Image not saving sometimes?

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, camera

I've looked for various bug reports for the iPhone SDK, but have not seen anything directly related to this bug.

I'm using a UIImagePickerController on the device to take a photo using the camera.  Sometimes (usually after the phone has been running for some time without a reset), I take my picture, and then select 'use' - but I get a nil image returned back in my delegate from the UIImagePickerController.  Once I've restarted the phone, everything goes back to normal for a while, but seems to eventually happen again.

This behaviour appears on iPhone devices for apps compiled using the 2.2.1, and 3.0 beta and final SDKs (and their associated ROM versions).

Has anyone else experienced this bug, or can you shed some light on it, or provide a solution to this issue?

Comment: This has been filed as Apple Bug ID# 6978412

Comment: do you know if your didReceiveMemoryWarning is being called?

Comment: That's a good point - I'll have to check.  I wonder if the camera SDK 'pass-through' uses a tmp directory somewhere that 'fills up' - in profiling in XCode, it does appear to be writing to flash.  If I open another application that uses the UIImagePicker, take a photo, then restart my app, the camera myseriously works again.  Very odd.  I doubt I'm receiving a mem warning though - my memory graph looks clean, no jumps, mem usage going back down after photo scale etc.

Comment: I seem to get a memory warning about 75% of the time that I take a picture...  I wish I knew what criteria the OS uses to decide that it's low on memory!